# update software

Tags: updates

I've just installed 20.10, and my software library indicates an update is required. Here is
the message I generate when I click update:

[image]

Comment: Try opening a terminal and run `sudo apt update` and if no errors from that also run `sudo apt upgrade` and update your question with the result ... especially if it fails. The two command if basically what the updater does, but sometimes easier to to find the error that way.

Comment: This was reported as Launchpad bug #1775226: [Gnome Software offers installation of updates on shutdown independently from update-manager and unattended-upgrades](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1775226). *It looks like that dialog should be displayed if the `/var/lib/PackageKit/prepared-update` file exists, which is what packagekit used to prepare offline updates. Those shouldn't happen on Ubuntu though. Do you have that file on your disk? What's the timestamp for it?*

Comment: Did what one suggested, no errors nor updates, using the sudo command. Software library still appears to believe there is an update.

Comment: Software app reports a packagekit pending update immediately after the software was updated from the terminal is a bug.

Comment: Looked for file, not theredavid@david-XPS-15-9530:~$ cd /var/lib/PackageKit/prepared-update
bash: cd: /var/lib/PackageKit/prepared-update: No such file or directory
david@david-XPS-15-9530:~$ cd /var/lib/PackageKit
david@david-XPS-15-9530:/var/lib/PackageKit$ ls -l
total 184
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 188416 Oct 27 08:23 transactions.db
david@david-XPS-15-9530:/var/lib/PackageKit$

Comment: No `/var/lib/PackageKit/prepared-update` file exists. That's normal so the terminal still updates the software properly with `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`, but the Software app has a bug.

Comment: Bascially use sudo for the time being

Comment: `pkcon -v refresh` any errors? `pkcon get-updates` is anything listed?

Comment: There was an error, ulauncher app, but I know of that error. Updates were okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt do-release-upgrade  # (if you want to upgrade to the latest version. ex: 20.04>20.10)
```

If one of this commands send a error, you may upload it in the forum too

Comment: The author of the question has mentioned that they're using Ubuntu 20.10. So, `sudo apt dist-upgrade` and `sudo apt do-release-upgrade` are not required. Please [edit] your answer.