# Unable to update/upgrade Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS

Tags: server, 22.04, lts

I keep getting the following error when trying to update or upgrade Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS

`E: Command line option 'p' [from -upgrade] is not understood in combination with the other options.`

I have been using the following commands

`sudo apt -upgrade` `sudo apt -update` `apt -upgrade apt -update`

How do I fix it?

Comment: Omit the hyphen:  sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade is what you need to type

Comment: Does this answer your question? [update software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287391/update-software)

Comment: I'm such an idiot. That worked perfectly, thank you

Answer (score 1):

This command isn't working because `update` is not a flag/option, it's a subcommand. The correct syntax for this is `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt upgrade` since `update` just updates the package index. More info can be found at the [manual page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/apt.8.html) for `apt`.

Comment: That's where I was going wrong! Thank you